# Login as windows domain user in linux through putty

Tags: linux, centos, windows-domain, centos-6

How can I configure CentOS 6 server to allow login through putty using Windows domain login? I have root access to CentOS but I am not Windows domain administrator. My Windows desktop where I can login using my Windows domain login and CentOS server are on same network.

Comment: Are you allowed to add computers to the domain? If yes, there are tutorials for configuring Samba (winbindd) as a domain member.

Comment: @grawity How to check that? I think I can not.

Comment: Have you asked the Windows domain admin for some help?

Comment: I think I should be able to configure without help of windows domain admin, because When I install Teamcity application on same server , users able to login to this application through browser using windows domain login and I didnt configure anything like domain/address etc. http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Configuring+Authentication+Settings#ConfiguringAuthenticationSettings-WindowsDomainAuthentication